# Do I have to wrap electrical connections with electrical tape?

Tags: ceiling-fan

I installed my first ceiling fan with remote today. I believe I did everything correctly as the fan turns and the light lights, both via the remote control.
My question has to do with the need for electrical tape.

I replaced an existing ceiling fan without a remote.  I disconnected the blue wire (lighting wire) from the group of existing wires. I then connected the black wire to the black wire and the white wire to the the white wire. I used the plastic caps originally used to twist the wires from the remote to the wires coming from the ceiling. There was no ground (copper) wire. The box and support was already sealed.

The only thing I didn't repeat in this process was to re-wrap black electrical tape around the plastic connector caps.

Here's the question; Is there going to be a problem down the road because I didn't wrap black electrical tape around the properly capped wires from the ceiling to the remote?

Answer (score 6):

As long as the twist-on wire connectors (colloquially known as "wire nuts", though that's a trademark) were the right size, attached firmly, and left no un-insulated wire exposed, electrical tape over them is unnecessary (and I believe is not recommended).

Comment: Technically they're called "*twist-on wire connectors*". "*WireNut®*" is a brand of twist-on wire connector, manufactured by Ideal.

Comment: I sit corrected and will correct. Interesting that they dropped the pre-twist; it always made _me_ feel more secure.

Comment: Wire nut is a perfectly accepted term in the electrical field. Sorry, I am NOT saying "twist-on wire connector" when I need one or need to refer to a wire nut. .................. Also, most now either say nothing, or they say "pre-twisting not required". I don't know of one that has said "do not pre-twist". To be honest I am not sure why this was even brought to the conversation. .... Either way, I will forever pre-twist anything more than 2 or 3 #14 wires, and this topic has been beaten to death on trade and DIY forums for years. It's worse than the receptacle ground up/down debate.

Comment: This answer is almost perfect. I would have said _"electrical tape over them IS unnecessary"_ ......... I have heard it said that folks tape wire nuts so they don't fall off. If tape is holding them on then you did it wrong.

Comment: Last I look to twist or not to twist we're both acceptable on Ideal brands.  I'm gonna have to agree with @Speedy Petey here on "proper terminology"

Comment: First draft of this answer brought up the twist issue; it sounds like better part of valor is to leave it unspecified. Compromise edit made re wire nuts; I agree that it's the term I've universally heard, but I can also understand why the trademark holder would be grumpy about that.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey When I said manufacturers don't recommend pretwisting, I didn't mean that they advise against it.  You can call twist-on connectors whatever you want, I was simply pointing out the "*proper*" name. Lastly, my comment was to a previous version of this answer.

Comment: Home Depot's "Wiring 1-2-3" recommends wrapping wire nuts and terminals with electrical tape because it "provides extra protection against dangerous ground faults and shorts". Is there a reason why this is a bad idea (even though the book says it is not required by code)?

Comment: @Jimmy Wrapping electrical tape around a wire nut after installation may accomplish three things: (1) If there was bare wire showing under the skirt of the wire nut, the tape covers it.  But if there's bare wire showing, it means too much insulation was stripped, and the connection should be disconnected and remade. (2) It may help keep the wire nut from falling off.  But a properly-installed wire nut won't fall off, and if it's loose enough to fall off, again, it means the connection is improper, and must be disconnected and remade properly.  (3) It creates a gooey mess.

Comment: About half the time I pull tape off a wire nut, the tape pulls the nut off the wires, and this means that *the connection was loose, and possibly either nonfunctional or dangerous, for all those years.*  Bottom line: Properly-installed wire nuts don't need tape.  At best, applying tape creates a gooey mess (if the connection was otherwise correct), and at worst, the tape covers up real, serious problems.  So I recommend strongly against it.

Comment: Probably not a bad idea for the people Hone Depot aimed that book at, though.